# 2 models in a form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model-associations

I am very new to rails development.
I am creating a simple backend for my portfolio site.

I am not sure about the title of this question. A previous question I asked maybe too convoluted. So I am simplifying it.

Im using 3 models: Post, Attachment, Attachment_Category

I have a form that I use to:

1. Draft the post with a title, content and a category.
2. Display attachment categories in a drop down (slideshow, image, video)
3. Upload the attachment(s).

I have implemented steps 1 and 2.

For step 3: I want it so that when I finally hit submit on the form, the attachment_category_id is saved to the attachment table.

I have the following relationships:

Post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :attachment_categories, :through => :attachments
has_many :attachments,:dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :attachments
validates_presence_of :title, :content, :category

end
```

Attachment.rb

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :post
belongs_to :attachment_category


#paperclip
has_attached_file :photo, :styles =>{

:thumb => "100x100#",
:small => "400x400>"

}

end
```

Attachment_category.rb

```
class AttachmentCategory < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :posts , :through => :attachments
has_many :attachments

validates :category_name, :presence =>true

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have accomplished Steps 1, parts of step 2 and step 3.

With my solution, I am able to upload just one attachment.
But it works: The attachment gets saved to the Attachments table with the post_id and the attachment_category_id.

The following code is from _form.html.erb which gets sent to post_controller.rb.
Truncated code:

```
.....

   <%= f.fields_for :attachments do |attach| %> <br>

   <%= attach.collection_select :attachment_category_id, AttachmentCategory.all, :id, :category_name %>
   <%= attach.file_field :photo %> <br>

   <% end %>

.....
```